# Marking up a comparison table with an empty top-left cell

Tags: html

I have a comparison table that is comparing two things on several properties. The way I have the table designed right now, the first column lists the properties the thing is being compared on, and the second and third columns list the values of the properties of the two things being compared. However, this leaves an empty cell in the top-left corner of the table. I'm wondering, what is the proper way to code this empty cell? I've read that it's bad practice to insert empty cells in tables.

Comment: You could put an animated gif in it, to entertain the user while fetching the data

Comment: An empty table cell seems most appropriate to me. Are you able to point to somewhere that says this is bad? If a table cell is empty I'm not sure there is much you can do apart from either leave it empty or put something in it (which you clearly don't want since you want it empty).

Comment: @Chris I wish I could remember the source, but I think it was an argument related to accessibility, and the suggestion was to use the colspan and rowspan attributes instead. But those don't seem appropriate in this particular case.

Comment: Ok, jokes apart, now the questions has more sense. Well, it is not good to have a lot of empty table cells, but just don't care for one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/15490/31314 , especially considering that an unwanted content in there, put only to avoid having the cell blank, would make a lot less sense

Comment: @AndreaLigios, yes, I think I'll just do the empty cell and be done with it. I appreciate a good joke, especially when it's accompanied by a useful answer afterward, which you (eventually) gave!